# logstash file input plugin configuration is not working

Tags: ruby

I have a problem with logstash when i want to **print logs to a file**.

This is my **output configuration**

```
if "ERROR" in [log]
{  
  file 
  {    
    path => "/home/yasmine/Bureau/elk/tri.text" codec => line 
    { 
      format => "Log: %log 
    }"            
  }
}
```

After running logstash it shows me this **error**

```
An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<Errno::EEXIST: File exists...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if "ERROR" in [log]
{  
  file 
  {    
    path => "/home/yasmine/Bureau/elk/tri.text" 
    codec => line { format => "Log: %{log}"}             
  }
}
```